# The resource cannot be found in IIS server 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to move a web site, with several web applications over to a new server running server 2012. The application was written in .net 3.5. I have been struggling through some issues but am now stuck on The resource cannot be found

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

 Requested URL: Any web app I tried URLs


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1087.0
```

I have tried running the app pool as .net 2.0. Enabled 32-bit applications. Set the security of the entire inetpub folder to allow all users full permission, still I am stuck. I also tried setting the application pool back to the default user. I get a 500 error then. The user I am running the app pool under is in the IIS_* group. The application pool is setup identical to that of the old server. The file does exist at the url I am trying and it is named correctly as I have tried it on several different applications within the site. It appears this is .net to blame more than IIS. Due to enterprise security I can't get remote debugging enabled on the server. Is there any logging that I can check to see why the page won't load?

Comment: Have you access to previous and actual server? web applications have not necessarily stay in inetpub folder. Have you copied the right folder structure? Have you configured sites in iis in the same way? Everyone full permission on websites folders is a good start. Are you trying application using a browser? From the same server or from another pc?

Comment: @Emanuele Yes I have access to both servers. I copied the correct directory. I'm using the broswer on the web server (aka localhost) I also tried binding it to the url and edited the hosts file. right now I am trying to create a simple website and get it to run.

Comment: HAve you enabled asp.net 4? Have you run aspnet_regiis -i command?

Comment: I'm in server 2012. aspnet_regiis should no longer be needed. I even removed the web server role from roles and features and readded everything. I did get another website running asp.net on the same IIS running just to verify .net was running properly. So now it has to be something with the page specifically. I wish it would give me a better error though

Comment: First IIS: If you can browse a page, the problem is in the website. MAybe a routing problem?

Comment: After spending way too much time I got the Fusion Log fully working. What was happening, although IIS was failing, even with full debug information enable, was to tell me there were more missing DLLs and dependencies. I found these missing DLLs and now it works

Comment: Fusion Log? So you missed saying something :)

Comment: Yes, what I don't get is I did exactly what it said to do in the registry. Still wasn't displaying anything. After more time searching for it, apparently there are other random registry keys that need to be set. Bless Microsoft